# Composition of a "List of lists" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to make the [composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations).
The relations are here represented with lists.

```
funComp :: Ord a => [[a,a]] -> [[a,a]] -> [[a,a]]
funComp [[a,b]] [[c,d]]
 | b == c = [[a,d]]
```

for example, given:

```
[[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3],[3,4],[4,4]]
```

and

```
[[1,4],[1,4],[2,3],[2,3],[3,2],[3,1],[4,1]]
```

should return:

```
[[1,4],[1,4],[1,3],[2,2],[2,1],[3,2],[3,1],[4,1]]
```

Comment: "trying to make the composition of relations". Can you state the problem clearly in terms of lists? Also presumably `funComp` is what you have so far but it's not clear where you're stuck, it looks like it starts to do something for arguments of length 1. What should it do when `b /= c`? That's a start

Comment: I recommend you start with simpler problems and approach this one later. There are several learning resources at [https://wiki.haskell.org/Learning_Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Learning_Haskell).

Answer (score 3):

I've included a full answer below, in the hopes that you might find it helpful.  I agree with @erisco that if you're just starting out, this problem might be a little advanced.  You might want to start with some problems that involve working with only *one* list/relation instead of combining two.  (For example, how would you make a relation antireflexive by removing all elements of the form *x R x*?  How would you produce the set of all values *y* such that *x R y* for a fixed value *x*?  Can you solve these problems both with built-in Haskell functions and from scratch?)

Anyway, to start, you may find it helpful, just from the standpoint of making it easier to read, to use tuples to represent the relation elements, so your two example relations would be:

```
r1 = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)]
r2 = [(1,4),(1,4),(2,3),(2,3),(3,2),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

What you are trying to do is construct is a relation consisting of all composite elements created from any ordered pair of elements from `r1` and `r2`.  This is the sort of thing a list comprehension is good for:

```
result = [ combine x y | x <- r1, y <- r2 ]
```

This expression creates a list of the result of running `combine x y` on each pair `x`,`y` from the two relations.  What should `combine` be?  Well, it takes two elements and generates their composition, so you might first try something like:

```
combine (a,b) (c,d) | b == c = (a,d)
```

This will type check, but `combine` is only a partial function -- it has no value for those pairs that don't combine -- so this won't get you too far.  You need a way of writing `combine` that allows you to return a combination *if* one exists but return nothing otherwise.

The standard way to do this in Haskell is using the `Maybe` type:

```
combine (a,b) (c,d) | b == c = Just (a,d)
                    | otherwise = Nothing
```

This type checks and runs, but the value of `result` looks like:

```
[Just (1,4),Just (1,4),Nothing,Nothing...]
```

Fortunately, there's a function in `Data.Maybe` called `catMaybes` that is exactly what we need for this situation -- it drops all the `Nothing`s and pulls the `Just` values together while dropping the literal `Just` constructors:

```
> catMaybes result
[(1,4),(1,4),(1,3),...]
```

There are some duplicates that should be removed, so let's remove them using `nub` from `Data.List`:

```
> nub (catMaybes result)
[(1,4),(1,3),(2,3),(2,2),(2,1),(3,2),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

which looks like the answer you probably wanted, though I think you missed `(2,3)` in your example output.

The full program, slightly generalized, looks like this:

```
module Relations where

import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

r1 = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)]
r2 = [(1,4),(1,4),(2,3),(2,3),(3,2),(3,1),(4,1)]

combine (a,b) (c,d) | b == c = Just (a,d)
                    | otherwise = Nothing

funcComp r1 r2
  = nub $ catMaybes [ combine x y | x <- r1, y <- r2 ]

result = funcComp r1 r2
```

If you haven't already:

- get in the habit of at least considering list comprehensions in any situation where you're generating items from one or more existing lists
- read the documentation for key modules like `Prelude`, `Data.List`, and `Data.Maybe` so you familiarize yourself with the functions that are available there

Answer (score 0):

A lot of mathematical definitions in terms of "set comprehensions" have fairly direct translations to list comprehensions.  The definition of (left to right) composition of relations is:

*R;S = { (x,z) | (x,y) ∈ R, (y,z) ∈ S }*

That is, x is related to z in the composite if you can from x to z by hopping to some y through R, then hopping from y to z through S.

You can translate this almost exactly -- we just need to split up the two mentions of y because you can only bind to fresh variables in a pattern.

```
compose r s = [ (x,z) | (x,y) <- r, (y',z) <- s, y == y' ]
```

To give it a type signature I would make a type synonym, then

```
type Relation a b = [(a,b)]
compose :: Relation a b -> Relation b c -> Relation a c
```

Notice that this is the opposite order from many definitions composition.  I just think with relations as sets of pairs it is particularly clear this direction and confusing the other way round.